# GitHub for Blender

Tags: python, scripting

Was exploring GitHub, has anyone used any premade python script from GitHub in Blender?
Also wanted some pointers on-

1. What blender resources are available on GitHub.
2. How can we best leverage GitHub for Blender especially animation and effects?
3. What are the free resources available?
4. How can I use python scripts available on GitHub for blender?

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate on what you mean with "Github for Blender" ? I don't remember this being a thing

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] below, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

Comment: I am a newbie at Blender and today while exploring GitHub I found some blender files on it- some scripting files etc. Wanted to understand how to best use GitHub to enable my blender journey.

here is something I found- https://github.com/p2or/blender-vfxtoolbox#build-empty

Comment: I guess this is what you want then ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11604587/7092409

Comment: let me explore this. Thank you